# CakePHP - Sharing Model/View/Controller using app:build()

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, overriding

Based on my understanding from this page: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html

I should be able to reference multiple models, views and controllers from different paths. And I can override MVC?

Here's my folder structure. I'm trying to put shared functionalities in the AppShared. And then in each app(app1, app2, etc..) to override views, and override/extend controllers....

In the bootstrap.php inside App1, I have

```
App::build(array(
    'Controller' => array(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH.'/AppShared/Controller/', ROOT.'/App1/Controller/'),
    'Model' => array(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH.'/AppShared/Model/', ROOT.'/App1/Model/'),
    'View' => array(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH.'/AppShared/View/', ROOT.'/App1/View/') 
));
```

**Root**
 - App1
   - Config
   - Controller
   - View
   - Model
   - ...
 - App2
 - lib
  - Cake
  - AppShared
     - Config
     - Controller
     - Model
     - View
     - ...

View inside App1 does not override the View inside AppShared... What did I do wrong??

Comment: Tried setting `App::RESET` as second parameter in `APP:build()` ? Also, are you sure the paths exists? What do your logs say?

Comment: Tried reset, doesnot work. Any other suggestions?